# Ubuntu / linux - Set permissions recursively through a folder where files/dirs have certain permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions

My title probably sounds more cryptic than it needs to.

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and want to be able to change permissions on files and folders recursively to 755 but only where the permissions are currently set to 777.

Does anybody know how to do this through the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
cd /the/dir
find . -perm 777 -exec chmod 755 {} +
```

Comment: Quite easy, yes, that's like you ask me the day of the week I'm born =)